# How to avoid database connection information in each perl file

Tags: database, perl

I am using number of perl scripts in my web project, which I am calling through jquery ajax calls. Each perl script contains mysql database connection information (user_name, password, database name).

Is there any better way, so that I can avoid database connection information in each perl file, and can store that globally, without any security issues.

Comment: may be to store it in one config file? something like config.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.pl`

```
{ 
  # sql credentials
  user => "sqluser", pass => "123", dsn => "mysql..",
}
```

`index.pl` and other scripts:

```
my $CFG = do "config.pl";
print "$CFG->{user} $CFG->{pass} ...\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more perlish option:

Config.pm

```
package Config;

sub get_config {
  return { 
    # sql credentials
    user => "sqluser", pass => "123", dsn => "mysql..",
  };
}
1; #return true from modules
```

index.pl and other scripts:

```
#make sure the current folder is in the lib path
#(if you have all in the same folder).
use FindBin; 
use lib $FindBin::Bin;

require Config;
my $cfg = Config->get_config();
print "$cfg->{user} $cfg->{pass} ...\n";
```

But I guess you got the consept, and TMTOWTDI.

Comment: [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) already exists, choose another name.